# Get QLabel's rectangle width

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I have the following code:

```
QLabel *la = new QLabel(ui->lineEdit->text());
la->setStyleSheet("background-color : #4682b4; color: white; font-size: 25px; padding: 8%;");
int w = la->fontMetrics().boundingRect(la->text()).width();
```

Problem is I can't the proper width of the QLabel. `w` is not considering the changes made with setStyleSheet(). I need to get the width of the rectangle which the text is inside. How do I do that?

Comment: try: `la->adjustSize();` `int w = la->sizeHint().width();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size updated on `paintEvent`, you can get size with zero timer.

```cpp
la->setStyleSheet("background-color : #4682b4; color: white; font-size: 25px; padding: 8%;");
QTimer::singleShot(0,[=](){
    int w = la->fontMetrics().boundingRect(la->text()).width();
});
```

or you can call `qApp->processEvents();` to spin event loop manualy.

```cpp
la->setStyleSheet("background-color : #4682b4; color: white; font-size: 25px; padding: 8%;");
qApp->processEvents();
int w = la->fontMetrics().boundingRect(la->text()).width();
```